# I have trouble keeping my skis parallel all the time. I have seen a teaching tool that connects the skis so they stay parallel. How is it called?

Tags: skiing

The tool connects two skis so they stay parallel, and allows for little margin. How is it called?

Comment: An Edgie Wedgie? Also known as ski tip connector.